# Grails 3.x - Creating test data for functional tests

Tags: grails, grails-orm, functional-testing, grails-3.3

I have a Grails application which is access control protected by Spring Security. 
I'm trying to create a test user and subsequently login using same from the login screen and then traverse my screens.
Seems like a reasonably common thing to try and do.

Yet, after (supposedly) successfully creating a test user (in the test Specification, not Bootstrap.groovy), same user is not found when trying to login.

When I do a User.list() in the application code (where I have a breakpoint at the point of login) there are none. But they exist in the test. It's like there are two separate sessions.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?
Happy to share code if there is not an obvious answer that I am missing.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing setup but what happens if you create the user in the relevant environments block in Bootstrap?

Comment: I would imagine it would work, but this is not how I would like to go about doing it. I'm going to fork the Grails guide on how to test Spring Security protected apps and try and work towards my requirement of creating test data per test fixture

Comment: Is your code creating the User in a "new transaction" block?
ie. : User.withNewTransaction { new User().save(flush: true) } ?

Comment: It is now, I'll update my answer

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the `@Rollback` annotation does more than was obvious to me.
And while (per the documentation) it;

> ensures that each test method runs in a transaction that is rolled back

it also creates a test-managed transaction that is completely independent of the application session. 
And so if the @Rollback annotation is being employed for my purpose above, a user created in the test (in `setup()` for example) will never be seen in the application and so the authentication logic of Spring Security will fail when it fails to load the user.

Note that after removing the `@Rollover` annotation, transaction blocks will have to be created manually with something like;

```
User.withTransaction {
 // ... do work here
}
```

Comment: I've tried to make this response more concise but maybe the down-voter can leave a comment describing their issue with it? I could after all have left no response at all after getting it to work but this would be of no value to the community.